# Issues with partitioning

Tags: partitioning, spool, eager

Looking for scale out option for my SQL server database.

I have a table that has 15 million rows and it adds 10,000 rows every day.
From various options available to scale out I opted for partitioning, as changes need to be done only in database and the application code will remain untouched.
Table I m partitioning is BOOKING table it has following columns:-
**1)**  Bookingid
**2)**  Ordered
**3)**  Userid
**4)**  Starttime
**5)**  Endtime
And many more

I decided to partition this table on yearly bases, so I selected Starttime column as my partition key.
First I created a copy of BOOKING table as BOOKING_Partition, imported all the data of Booking table into Booking_Partition table.

**Steps followed for partitioning:-**
**1)**  Create file groups
**2)**  Attach files to file groups
**3)**  Create partition function
**4)**  Create partition scheme 
**6)**  Created cluster index with Starttime (partition key) and Bookingid (I used combination) on partition scheme
**7)**  Finally I checked by running query if partitioning was successful. Yes my table was partitioned successfully.

Now I wanted to check my existing query if there was any performance change
I checked query that was most frequently used, if fetches data for 40 days whenever application loads

SELECT Bookingid, OrderId, UserId FROM Booking_Partition WHERE Starttime >= GETDATE()-20 AND Starttime < GETDATE()+20

Above is just an example, on production this query has joins to get data from other table.
When I run this query on partition table and on non partition table profiler shows me almost same duration, there is no difference in performance.

**Image for Select query execution plan:-**
 [image: Image for Select query execution plan]

Above plan is for partitioned table, it shows hitting the partition, but as I said profiler is showing no change in duration for partitioned and non partition table.
Also I can’t understand why it is hitting 4 partitions for fetching 40 days of data.

Now my main concern arrives when I do UPDATE or DELETE.
 
When I update or delete on partition table it shows eager spool in execution plan.

**Image for Update query execution plan showing eager spool:-**
[image: Image for Update query execution plan showing eager spool]

I can’t understand why it is doing eager spool only when I am updating or deleting on partition table, same query when I run on non partition table it does not do eager spool.